# Shell: How to check available space and exit if not enough?

Tags: linux, shell

I want to check if I do have enough space before executing my script.
I thought about

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
cd
Home=$(pwd)
reqSpace=100000000
if [ (available Space) < reqSpace ]
    echo "not enough Space"
    exit 1
fi
do something
```

The space I want to check via

```
df | grep $Home
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Consider running code through http://shellcheck.net/ before posting it here; this will find, for instance, the incorrect use of `<` in `[ ]`.

Comment: Also, you can run `df "$Home"` much more efficiently than `df | grep "$Home"` (*without* the quotes, you've got bugs if your directory has spaces).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Bringing it all together (`set -e` and `cd` omitted for brevity; Bash-specific syntax - not POSIX-compliant):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Note: Numbers are 1024-byte units on Linux,
#       and 512-byte units on macOS.
reqSpace=100000000
availSpace=$(df "$HOME" | awk 'NR==2 { print $4 }')
if (( availSpace < reqSpace )); then
  echo "not enough Space" >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

`df "$HOME"` outputs stats about disk usage for the `$HOME` directory's mount point, and `awk 'NR==2 { print $4 }'` extracts the (POSIX-mandated) 4th field from the 2nd output line (the first line is a header line), which contains the available space in 1024-byte units on Linux<sup>[1]</sup>, and 512-byte units on macOS; enclosing the command in `$(...)` allows capturing its output and assigning that to variable `availSpace`.

Note the use of `(( ... ))`, an arithmetic conditional, to perform the comparison, which allows:

- referencing variables without their `$` prefix, and
- use of the customary arithmetic comparison operators, such as `<` (whereas you'd have to use `-le` if you used `[ ... ]` or `[[ ... ]]`)

Finally, note the `>&2`, which redirects the `echo` output to *stderr*, which is where error messages should be sent.

---

<sup>[1] If you define the `POSIXLY_CORRECT` environment variable (with any value), the GNU implementation of `df` too uses the POSIX-mandated 512-byte units; e.g., `POSIXLY_CORRECT= df "$HOME"`.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it

```
df "$Home" | awk 'END{print $4}'
```

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
cd
Home=$PWD
reqSpace=100000000
SPACE=`df "$Home" | awk 'END{print $4}'`
if [[ $SPACE -le reqSpace ]]
then
    echo "not enough Space"
    exit 1
fi
do something
```

Comment: Only thing missing is a comparison (since the OP *is* doing that wrong, it's something an answer should cover).

Comment: If you're going to use bash-only syntax, might as well make it `(( SPACE <= reqSpace ))`.

Comment: (And btw, all-caps variable names aren't good form; the OP is actually doing it right by having at least one lower-case variable in their own names: This prevents conflicting with variables having meaning to the system or shell; see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, fourth paragraph -- specifying naming convention for environment variables, but updating a shell variable overwrites any like-named environment variable, so it applies in both cases).

Comment: df "$Home" won't work as pwd doesn't print my whole directory. Thats why I search for it with grep. I had awk in my mind, but I didnt knew I could print it. I gonna try it at home.

Comment: @ChrizZly, try it. `df` works even when given a location *under* a mount point, rather than the name of the mount point itself.

Comment: @ChrizZly, ...btw, consider `$PWD` instead of `$(pwd)` -- considerably more efficient, since it doesn't involve spawning a subshell.